# mysql query parameter string array

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pass a parameter to a query, rather than write copious text I have narrowed it down to this simple explanation.
The frament I am trying to insert into is

```
where pkw_0.keyword in (:kwd)
```

I have used a String[] to construct a string of the form vals="'AVal','BVal'" which I pass to the query using setParameter("kwd",vals); The query returns zero results.  However if I construct the query by hand and use the mysql console the query returns 1 result which is expected.

So I am assuming that either a single string is incorrect for the parameter or there is some conditioning of the values that I need to do prior to passing them via the setParameter call.

Answer (score 1):

Each parameter can only represent a *single* literal value.  You will need to create multiple placeholders in your prepared statement (one for each value) and then provide each value to MySQL as a separate parameter.

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is I have a variable number of values so I cannot predict how many or even what the maximum number of values there will be.  So I think you are saying that given these conditions I cannot substitute into the '('...')' in a setParameter, do you have any suggestions for an alternative (other than attempting to preset the number of values)

Comment: @JeffLowcock:  What language are you using?  Why can you not count the number of elements in your array?

Comment: It is all java - it is not the counting of the arguments that is the problem.  I have simplified this (perhaps too far)  I am actually using a namedNativeQuery with the associated SqlResultMapping so dynamically creating this is probably not possible.  Hence the original approach - which may simply not be possible.

Comment: I found a link here http://www.coderanch.com/t/415118/ORM/databases/JPA-Query-where-setParameter that is right on target the solution is to pass to setParameter a List<String> which then is managed to create the correct query and I get the results that I expect.  So thanks for the clues and assist and we have both learnt something new today.